# Const, pure member function called from multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop

For my computation, I need to perform a specific task. To do this task, I encapsulate all of the data and that function into one object:

Check.h:

```
#pragma once
#include<vector>
#include<atomic>
using namespace std;
using digit = short;

class Check
{
private:
        digit length, del;
        vector< vector<bool> > routes;
public:
        Check(digit length, digit del);
        void is_compatible(int first, int second, atomic_bool& result) const;
        ~Check();
};
```

Check.cpp:

```
#include"Check.h"
#include<algorithm>
using namespaced std;

Check::Check(digit length_, digit del_) : length(length_), del(del_)
{
        //first iteration
        vector<bool> iter(del*2);

        for (int i = iter.size() - 1; i >= del; i--)
        {
                iter[i] = 1;
        } //by the end, iter = {0,0,1,1} if del = 2 

        //get the rest of the permutations
        do
        {
                routes.push_back(iter);
        } while (next_permutation(iter.begin(), iter.end()));
}

void Check::is_compatible(int first, int second, atomic_bool& result)
{
    for (auto& route : routes)
    {
         //some calculations using each route
         if (condition) result = false;
    }
}
```

If I were to try to call this code:

```
Check check(4,2);
atomic_bool answer = true;
thread worker1(&Check::is_compatible, check, 0, 0, ref(answer));
thread worker2(&Check::is_compatible, check, 1, 1, ref(answer));
worker1.join(); worker2.join();
if (answer) //do something
```

Would the threads actually be working at the same time? They would each need to read values from check.routes, so would there be problems accessing that portion of memory from multiple threads? Would it be better to give each thread its own Check object?

Also, am I using atomic types correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: What if one thread sets `result` to `false` and the other doesn't? Which is the "true" value of `result`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude With how atomics work, I believe `result` will be then set to `false`. The function cannot change `result` back to `true`.

Comment: It is safe to access a vector from multiple threads as long as you do not modify it. If you do modify it, there is the potential that all iterators are invalidated (if a reallocation is performed for example).

Comment: @Jeff: To be honest it looks alright, however is the boolean really a switch that never flips back to `true`? That is, if any one thread determines it to be `false`, it should be `false` for all threads? I think this is what Some programmer dude was getting at.